# Matrix times vector in keras

Tags: keras

I want to do a product of a matrix M x N (M timestamps with N fractures each) and a vector M x 1 to get a vector of size N x 1, so the timestamp dimension is eliminated. How can I do that?

Comment: Please provide some code that illustrates what exactly you want to do and where you are stuck as this is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

An example:

```
import keras.backend as K

a = K.constant([[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
print(a.shape)
b = K.constant([[1],[2]])
print(b.shape)
result = K.dot(K.transpose(a),b)
print(result.shape)

print(K.eval(result))

# print
(2, 3)
(2, 1)
(3, 1)

[[3.]
 [6.]
 [9.]]
```